# Git replace an entire directory

Tags: git-merge, git-rm, git

I have a directory in git that needs to be replaced with a new one.
The new directory has few files modified, removed and also few files same.

**E.g.:**

```
**Currently in the repo**

DirA

|-> FileA, FileB
|->DirB
|   |-> FileC, FileD
|-> FileE, FileF

**New Directory:**

DirA
|-> FileA, FileB, FileG
|->DirB
|   |-> FileC, FileD
|-> FileE
```

I cannot push without replacing as I have local test performed on the repository

I am doing this currently,

```
git rm DirA
git commit -m "removing DirA"
git pull DirA
```

I am getting merge conflicts (DU) on files under DirA even though I removed them.
I am assuming its due to the "push" not being done.

Is there a workaround for this?
Or, If I were to select the new file in the merge conflict i.e. the copied file, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Vinay

Comment: From what I can see, you're just adding a new file and removing an old file. Why would you think to kill the entire directory?  This is throwing out the baby with the bathwater IMHO.  Just make the changes, then add and commit them.  Leave the folder alone.

Comment: There are few thousand files in the repo. The new repo should not have any of the old files. Also, there are few files modified, where I need to take the modified file. In short I need only the content of new directory.

Comment: I think you're starting with a bad mental model of how Git works. You'd be well served by working through a good [book on Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Don’t keep each directory in a separate branch.

Comment: @torek: If you are talking about the version control aspect I understand that. 
But this is a special requirement where I need to keep the new version of the directory enirely (I don't want the previous version info)

so as I see it, there are two options:

(Options1)
1. Replace the entire directory or,

(Option2)
1. Remove all files that are not present in new directory
2. Add all files that are present only in new directory
3. Do a git merge on hundred to thousands of files.

Comment: @torek: Also thanks for the link. I am new to git (came from perforce background). I will be going though it.

Comment: While I have not used Perforce, I believe p4 has the notion of *file identity* tied to the act of creating a file, so that if you remove a file named `dir/file.ext` and create a new `dir/file.ext`, p4 knows these are two different files. Git *does not* do this: each snapshot contains all the files, regardless of what's in any other snapshot, and it's at `git diff` time that Git tries to decide whether some earlier `dir/file.ext` is "the same file" as some later `dir/file.ext`. My own book is far from finished but in one of the early chapters, I try to get at this concept. 1/2

Comment: Because Git identifies files late in the game, and does not record directories at all (nor directory changes), this gives it certain advantages and disadvantages compared to almost every other VCS. The short version is: Git is weird. :-) 2/2